# difference between type of new lines

Tags: python, document, python-docx

I have two document one is .txt file and another is .docx file. I converted .txt file to document file using pyhton-docx.

```
with open(out_file_path,'r') as text_file:
    book_text = text_file.read()
```

and then

```
document.add_paragraph(book_text)
document.save('abc.dox')
```

[image: difference in docs]

I dot different new lines in two but i want the converted docx file to have the same 'P' instead f return(enter symbol)

Comment: The "P" symbol means paragraph break. So instead of creating a single paragraph with the entire file contents, you probably want to call `add_paragraph` for each line in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

The 'line ending' you're looking for is really a paragraph ending (the 'P' you mentioned).

Whether this is really a better solution is open for debate, but if you want each line in the text file to become a paragraph in the `.docx`, this is a way to do it:

```
from docx import Document

with open('text.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    book_text = text_file.read().splitlines()

doc = Document()
for line in book_text:
    doc.add_paragraph(line)
doc.save('test.docx')
```

Note that, instead of storing all the text of the file as a single string in `book_text`, it is storing it as a list of strings, split at the line endings.

And instead of then adding the entire contents as a single paragraph, it loops over all the strings in the list, adding each as a separate paragraph.